# Decrease Audit.Net time while creating audit entries

Tags: audit-logging, audit-trail, audit.net

**Current Scenario**

- We have an endpoint and it has an entity and in that entity it has List of other entity.
- When we send request to it without Audit.Net configurations the
  response time can be 710ms to 723ms.
- But when we add Audit.Net, the response time increases to 1123ms i.e it comes in 4 digits value.

**Feature Requested**

- Any one of the following features can be added:
- Our main concern is to add such feature through which we just trigger it on starting and it keep tracking entities and creating their logs on background without increasing response time.
- Second one is to just reduce the Audit.Net time in creating audit logs
- Third one is to make it as a separate service, in which we just pass the url of running project which we want to track and it keep tracking logs of it.

*Please comment any other package which has audit feature*

Comment: What are you auditing and where are you saving the audits?